# How is branching logic coded when dealing with a checkbox answer in RedCAP?

Tags: checkbox, branching-strategy, redcap

This is my branching logic for the progress bar on one of the questions before we get to the checkbox one: ( this works)

([age]<>"" AND [education]="" AND        [relationship_to_child]="" AND [are_you_the_sole_caregiver]="" AND [how_many_dependent_childre]="" AND [language]="" AND       [what_is_your_suburb]="" AND [are_you_of_aboriginal_or_t(1)]="" AND [are_you_of_aboriginal_or_t(2)]="" AND [are_you_of_aboriginal_or_t(3)]="" AND [are_you_of_aboriginal_or_t(4)]="" )

However, once I get to the checkbox question, I am a bit stuck.

I have tried the logic below, using OR between each of the checkbox answers, but it doesn’t work.

([age]<>"" AND [education]<>"" AND      [relationship_to_child]<>"" AND [are_you_the_sole_caregiver]<>"" AND [how_many_dependent_childre]<>"" AND [language]"" AND       [what_is_your_suburb]="" AND ([are_you_of_aboriginal_or_t(1)]<>"" OR [are_you_of_aboriginal_or_t(2)]<>"" OR [are_you_of_aboriginal_or_t(3)]<>"" OR [are_you_of_aboriginal_or_t(4)]<>"" ))

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have just forgotten to close out the parentheses. See the bolded parentheses below:

```
([age]<>"" AND [education]<>"" AND [relationship_to_child]<>"" AND 
[are_you_the_sole_caregiver]<>"" AND [how_many_dependent_childre]<>"" 
AND [language]"" AND [what_is_your_suburb]="" AND **(**
([are_you_of_aboriginal_or_t(1)]<>""**)** OR **(**
[are_you_of_aboriginal_or_t(2)]<>""**)** OR **(**
[are_you_of_aboriginal_or_t(3)]<>""**)** OR **(**
[are_you_of_aboriginal_or_t(4)]<>"" ))
```

Let me know if this doesn't work, and I can look into this further.